# CDI with Weld in Java SE, jakarta namespace, NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, cdi, nosuchmethoderror, weld, jandex

For a trivial app using CDI in Java SE with jakarta namespace I can not get rid of this `NoSuchMethodError` during `SeContainerInitializer.newInstance().initialize()`:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Map org.jboss.jandex.ClassInfo.annotationsMap()'`

I guess I'm missing dependencies. Shouldn't this be sufficient?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

`beans.xml` is in place at `src/main/resources/META-INF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that works for me is to exclude jandex from hibernate dependency and to add an individual jandex dependency to the project. Here is an excerpt from my pom.xml:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.14.Final</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <!-- without exclusion of jandex in hibernate a no such method error is raised -->
                    <!-- with    exclusion an explicit dependency to jandex is needed (see below)  -->
                    <!-- note that jandex is referenced with groupId io.smallrye actually          -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!-- individual dependency to jandex to accomplish necessary exclusion of jandex in -->
            <!-- hibernate-core-jakarta (see above)                                             -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
```